# Excel VBA - Using the Split function but with multiple/variable strings

Tags: vba, excel, split

I have a column with dozens/hundreds of different names, some listed multiple times.  Each name is formatted as firstname.lastname.  I need to split these up to be correctly listed as firstname lastname.  Using the split function, usually the first parameter is the string you need to split.

I have used this before with an array of items to split, but I have always had to list each item in the array.  This, of course, is not possible with hundreds of different names.

I have searched, but every answer I find always uses an array, or is discussing how to split into multiple columns.

How can it be written so that the code could loop through the entire column (B, in this case) and split every name, while keeping everything in the one column?

The code will be something like:

```
nameSplit = Split(all_names_in_column_B, ".")
```

Comment: Big difference between dozens and hundreds/

Comment: It sounds more like you are trying to replace the periods with a space. Kinda a confusing question.

Comment: Why not use substitute function or replace?

Comment: Fair enough.  Let's say the range is 96 to 200 names.  Then it covers what I said.

Comment: Yes, I could use those, actually.  Never thought of that, as I have always (only like 3 or 4 other instances, actually) used split to do something like this.  Sounds like it would be easier the entire time to use one of those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select the column, press control and F to bring up Find and Replace, Find "." and replace enter a space (by pushing the spacebar once). Does assume you don't have other text within the cells containing periods.

You could do the same thing in VBA.

```
Sub TEST()

ActiveSheet.Columns("A").Replace _
 What:=".", Replacement:=" ", _
 SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The code to do this looks like this

```
Public Sub SplitTest()

    Dim ws As Worksheet                             'Declare a worksheet variable
    Dim sheetName As String: sheetName = "Sheet1"   'Provide the name of the sheet where the data is located
    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(sheetName)       'Assign it to the worksheet variable

    Dim inputRng As Range                           'Declare a range variable
    Dim rangeName As String: rangeName = "B1:B5"    'Assign the range location using whatever method you like to select your range
    Set inputRng = ws.Range(rangeName)              'Assign the range to the range variable

    Dim splitStringArray() As String                'Declare a variable length array of strings to hold the result of the split
    Const FirstName = 0                             'FirstName is element 0 of splitStringArray
    Const LastName = 1                              'LastName is element 1 of splitStringArray
    Dim enumRng As Range                            'Declare a range variable to be used as an enumerator
    For Each enumRng In inputRng                    'Loop through the range one cell at a time
        splitStringArray = Split(enumRng, ".")      'Split the value located in the cell
        enumRng.Value2 = splitStringArray (FirstName) & " " & splitStringArray (LastName)   'Overwrite the value in the current cell with the First and Last Names
                                                                'separeated by a space, this could be anything
    Next enumRng

End Sub
```

Comment: What is `sfl(...)` (isn't declared anywhere)?

Comment: Forgot to change the name sfl was a quickie name I used while dev/test.  I then changed the name to something more meaningful.

Comment: Thanks for info. BTW, using `splitStringArray = Split(enumRng & ".", ".")` you avoid a possible error if there is no point delimiter at all (e.g. an empty cell or given name only).